# How to get xposed framework on Lollipop (Samsung)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, xposed-framework

I am on Samsung Galaxy note 3 SM-n900 Android 5.0 Stock Firmware (API-21). I am able to install xposed framework easily on Kitkat and Jellybean, however, i want to be on lollipop and cannot figure out how to get xposed on my device. i flashed CWM recovery first, then i installed this file "xposed-v84-sdk21-arm.zip" via CWM and my device is stuck on samsung logo forever!

[here is the link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)

I was able to flash exposed framework on Cyanogenmod 12.1 but not on samsung lollipop

Comment: Search for **xposed-v75-sdk21-arm.zip**, or a version lesser than 75 if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm running CM12.1 with **xposed-v75-sdk22-arm**. I'm unsure as if it will work for you, but you may want to give it a try. Also, the Xposed dev made a framework uninstaller, which is flashable as well.

Comment: Xposed runs on my deodexed CyanogenMod.

Comment: My advice, as I said, is to try with v75 or lesser. Plus, you shouldn't need to flash your ROM, since the dev made that uninstaller.

Comment: The **Xposed Framework** causes the bootloop. The **uninstaller** removes the **Xposed Framework**.

Comment: @abbie That's not bootloop I guess.. Flashing xposed clears the Dalvik cache and rebuilds it (You will see 'Optimizing apps' soon).. Wait for 10-15mins to confirm if it's bootloop. // I just saw this on that thread: "**Bootloops on Samsung stock ROMs. That's due to Samsung's changes to ART. There are unofficial builds that work around this by deodexing and adjusting the ROM.**" So, It maybe a bootloop, IDK :/

Comment: i did not see "'Optimizing apps' soon" it's been 40 minutes, i know what a boot loop is, i have been flashing ROMs on this device for years

Comment: and i don't need an unofficial build since the official builds are out i guess. The official page says, i need a deodexed ROM. I wish there was a xposed lollipop rom for my device

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung Stock ROMs (based on TouchWiz UI), you have to flash the **[Arter's Xposed for Samsung Lollipop 5.0.x deodexed ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3113463)** or **[Wanam's Xposed for Samsung Lollipop 5.1.x/ Marshmallow 6.0.x ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960)**, instead of the [rovo89's Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) which is basically for AOSP & CM-based ROMs.

Comment: That's because ART came into effect since Lollipop.. See the title of that thread.. It says Xposed for "Samsung Lollipop/Marshmallow". Why don't you just believe and try it ? :) :) If it doesn't work, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @abbie , if you are so sure we're all wrong here, why don't you answer your own question and elaborate how the correct procedure is, plus where to find the "official builds" which you say are "out you guess"? Your current comments are rather suited to scare people off instead of helping you.

Comment: lmfao im trying to convert nandroid backup to a flashable zip, and then deodex it using some tool, flash it back, install an official/unofficial xposed. thats my plan

Comment: Ever since Lollipop 5.0, Samsung ship their stock ROMs with a **heavily modded** ART. That the primary cause for original Xposed framework not working well on Samsung stocks.